# Check if other files were modified in a commit series in git

Tags: git

Suppose I have a file `mocky.cpp`, I would like to list commits that modified the file, and also list another files that were touched by these commits.
So I try the following:

```
git log --name-only -- mocky.cpp
```

I get a list of commits, that is nice, strangely, however, all the commits do not modify a file except from `mocky.cpp`. I check one of them, say, e013aac, w/ `git show e013aac` and I find out it also changes `testy.hpp`.
Moreover, I found that `git show e013aac -- mocky.cpp` only outputs the diff for the `mocky.cpp` but not for the `testy.cpp`
This is most counter-intuitive to me, anyway, how could I achieve what I wanted in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
git log --format=%H -- mocky.cpp | xargs git show --stat
```

Or modify it for your needs like:

```
git log --format=%H -- mocky.cpp | xargs git show --name-only
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is best practive, but the command below might do what you intend:

```
for SHA in $(git log --format='%H' your_file.cpp) ; do git diff-tree --name-only -r $SHA ; done
```